# MIT Kerberos sname types

Tags: kerberos

I have a kerberos service which I can ask a ticket for with kinit and knvo. I can see in wireshark that the sname is set to KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL. I'm trying to generate a ticket with the MIT C API, but it cannot find the service. I noticed in WireShark that the difference is in the sname. With the c code, it sends the sname-type as "KRB5_NT_SRV_HST" and it fails. I tried to set the service_principal type to KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL but it still doesn't work. The requests fails in krb5_mk_req function, which is the TGS-REQ message. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <krb5.h>
#include <com_err.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define TKT_LIFETIME 30
#define NO_REPLAYCACHE

static void syslog_err(const char* tag, long code, const char*format, va_list args){
    printf("%s: %s in %s\n", tag, error_message(code), format);
}

#define check_code(err, tag)\
    if(err){\
        void (*proc)(const char*, long, const char*, va_list);\
        proc=set_com_err_hook(syslog_err);\
        com_err("ERROR: ",(err),(tag));\
        (void)set_com_err_hook(proc);\
        goto cleanup;\
    }

int main() {
    const char *username="foo@BAR";
    const char *password="foobar";
    //const char *host="foobar";

    const char kt_pathname[256] = "/etc/krb5.keytab";
    char service[256]="krbtgt";
    char host[256]="BAR";
    krb5_error_code err;
    krb5_error_code err_t;
    krb5_context context;
    krb5_auth_context auth_context = NULL;
    krb5_creds credentials;
    krb5_principal user_principal,
                    service_principal;
    krb5_verify_init_creds_opt vic_options;
    krb5_keytab keytab=NULL;
    krb5_ccache ccache;
    //char ccache_name[L_tmpnam + 8];
    char ccache_name[19]="/tmp/krb5cc_XXXXXX";
    krb5_get_init_creds_opt * gic_options;
#ifndef NO_REPLAYCACHE
    krb5_verify_init_creds_opt vic_options;
#endif
    krb5_data apreq_pkt;
    char myhostname[256],sprinc[256];
    int have_user_principal =0,
        have_service_principal=0,
        have_keytab=0,
        have_credentials=0,
        success=-1,
        ccache_retval;
    apreq_pkt.data=NULL;

    err = krb5_init_context(&context);
    check_code(err, "failed to init krb5 context");

    ccache_retval = mkstemp(&ccache_name[12]);
    if (ccache_retval == -1) printf("Error: failed to create a cache file");
    err = krb5_cc_resolve(context,ccache_name,&ccache);
    check_code(err, "fill a ccache file");

    err = krb5_parse_name(context, username, &user_principal);
    check_code(err, "parse principal name");
    have_user_principal=1;

    err = krb5_cc_initialize(context,ccache,user_principal);
    check_code(err, "initialize cc cache");

    (void) memset( (char*)&credentials, 0, sizeof(credentials));

    krb5_get_init_creds_opt_alloc(context, &gic_options); // Allocate a new initial credential options structure
    krb5_get_init_creds_opt_set_tkt_life(gic_options, TKT_LIFETIME); // Set the ticket lifetime in initial credential options

    err = krb5_get_init_creds_password(context, &credentials, user_principal,password,0,0,0,NULL,gic_options); //Get initial credentials using a password
    check_code(err, "get initial credentials")

    // at this point, we have a ticket (stored in credentials)
    err = krb5_cc_store_cred(context, ccache, &credentials); // Store credentials in a credential cache
    err_t=err;
    check_code(err, "store credentials");
    if(err_t) have_credentials=1;


    err = krb5_sname_to_principal(context,host,service,KRB5_NT_SRV_HST,&service_principal); //Generate a full principal name from a service name KRB5_NT_UNKNOWN
    check_code(err, "sname_to_principal");
    service_principal->type=KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL;

    have_service_principal=1;

    err = krb5_kt_resolve(context,kt_pathname,&keytab); //Get a handle for a key table
    check_code(err, "kt_resolve");
    have_keytab=1;


#ifndef NO_REPLAYCACHE

    krb5_verify_init_creds_opt_init(&vic_options); //Initialize a credential verification options structure
    krb5_verify_init_creds_opt_set_ap_req_nofail(&vic_options,1); //Set whether credential verification is required
    err = krb5_verify_init_creds(context, &credentials, service_principal, keytab,0,&vic_options); //Verify initial credentials against a keytab
    check_code(err,"verify init credentials");
#else

    err = krb5_mk_req(context,&auth_context,0,service,host,NULL,ccache,&apreq_pkt);
    check_code(err, "apreq_pkt request");
    if(auth_context){
        krb5_auth_con_free(context,auth_context); //Free a krb5_auth_context structure.
        auth_context=NULL;
    }
    err = krb5_auth_con_init(context,&auth_context); //Create and initialize an authentication context
    check_code(err, "auth init");
    err = krb5_auth_con_setflags(context,auth_context,~KRB5_AUTH_CONTEXT_DO_TIME); //Set a flags field in a krb5_auth_context structure
    check_code(err, "auth set flags");
    err = krb5_rd_req(context,&auth_context,&apreq_pkt,service_principal,keytab,NULL,NULL); // This function parses, decrypts and verifies a AP-REQ message
    check_code(err, "decrypt & verify AP-REQ message");
    if(auth_context){
        krb5_auth_con_free(context,auth_context); //Free a krb5_auth_context structure.
        auth_context=NULL;
    }
#endif
    err = krb5_cc_destroy(context,ccache);
    if (err!=0)
        printf("[*] Failed to destroy kerberos context \n");
    else
        success=1;
*/


    cleanup:
    if(apreq_pkt.data)
        krb5_free_data_contents(context,&apreq_pkt); // Free the contents of a krb5_data structure and zero the data field
    if(have_keytab){
        krb5_kt_close(context,keytab);
        if (err!=0)
            printf("[*] Failed to destroy the keytab \n"); //Close a key table handle
    }

    krb5_cc_destroy(context,ccache);
    if(have_user_principal)
        krb5_free_principal(context,user_principal);
    if(have_service_principal)
        krb5_free_principal(context,service_principal);
    if(have_credentials)
        krb5_free_cred_contents(context,&credentials);
    if(context)
        krb5_free_context(context);


    return 0;
}
```

the krb5.conf files both in client& server machine:

```
KDC & Client krb5.conf:
[libdefaults]
    encryption & properties
    .
    .
    .
    default_realm = TEST1.EXAMPLE.COM

[domain_realms]
    .test1.example.com = TEST1.EXAMPLE.COM
    test1.example.com = TEST1.EXAMPLE.COM
[logging]
    files configurations
    .
    .  
    .
[realms]
    TEST1.EXAMPLE.COM = {
    kdc = TEST1.EXAMPLE.COM:88
    default_domain = TEST1.EXAMPLE.COM
    admin_server=TEST1.EXAMPLE.COM
    }
```

where TEST1.EXAMPLE.COM is the realm of them (client & server & application server). each computer ip address is mapped in the /etc/hosts file, i.e: 192.168.x.x

Thank you!

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux here?  Can we see the krb5.conf?  Is your client and server machine actively in a domain/realm?

Comment: Hi @T-Heron , https://pastebin.com/f7rqKCZg . I'm using /etc/hosts configuration instead of DNS server (I have a very very small network). I'm using only linux.
(Can I ask help privately somehow? It's rare I find someone how actually understands kerberos. Thank you and sorry if it's inappropriate)

Comment: You'll find it very rare that someone is willing to help privately.  After all, answers here are already given out of someone's own free time, and what that question basically is asking, is for even *more* free help.  Doubt you'll find anyone who would do that.  After all, this is supposed to be a free, public community.   You should edit your question to now include your pastebin notation and the other comments.

Comment: Please also indicate as to whether your client and server machine are joined to a domain/realm and if this entire setup is all on one machine or not.

Comment: Hi again @T-Heron, I have updated the question as you mentioned. The entire setup includes 3 computers: client, server and application server. I have followed the MIT Kerberos setup (Which is horribly, very horribly written. Excuse me for that). I'm able to generate a "KRB5_NT_PRINCIPLE" ticket with kvno command via my client computer to the application server. But when trying to generate a ticket with kerberos api, it automatically requests from the tgs a ticket with sname type "KRB5_NT_SRV_HST" and fails.

Comment: I have also noticed (with Wireshark) that both of the requests (via kvno and kerberos c api) are the same except the sname type & the host address letters. with kvno, they are capitalized and with the kerberos api they are not.